# Replacing a character plus newline with a string

Tags: linux, command-line

Taking a file with DHCP host definitions as input I need to transform entries like:

```
host mx {
 fixed-address 10.0.1.161;
```

into entries like this:

```
host mx - fixed-address 10.0.1.161;
```

(obviously I need to output this to `stdout`, not replace those entries in place)

`sed` doesn't work because it basically doesn't allow replacing newlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a very short Perl one liner:

```
$ perl -pe 's/{\n/-/' file
host mx - fixed-address 10.0.1.161;
```

Answer (score 2):

`sed` is able to delete the newline:

```
$ printf 'host mx {\n  fixed-address 10.0.1.161;\n' | sed '/{$/{N; s/{\n */- /; }' 
host mx - fixed-address 10.0.1.161;
```

This command deletes the final `{` and the newline on all lines that end in `{`, which may not be quite what you want.  If the `mx` records you are trying to change are multi-line, you'll need to add more logic, and perhaps you want to limit this further with `/host mx {^/ ...`, but you would need to add more detail to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an awk to do what is described:

```
printf 'host mx {\n  fixed-address 10.0.1.161;\n' | awk -F "[ \t]*\\\{" '/^host mx/{
    getline l2
    sub(/^[ \t]*/,"",l2)
    printf "%s - %s\n", $1, l2
}'
```

Prints:

```
host mx - fixed-address 10.0.1.161;
```